# PHP Extract key values from nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I have an API call that returns the following array.  What I'm trying to do in PHP is grab the key values for ONLY the objects in the [by_category] array.  I want to display only the category name and the value for views for that array.  But I'm stuck on how to loop through these nested arrays to get at only those values, ignoring everything in the [by_date] array.  Any tips on where to start?  Any example code I can fiddle with?

```
Array
(
    [by_date] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 2016-11-10
                [views] => 1202
                [participations] => 29
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 2016-09-10
                [views] => 2068
                [participations] => 66
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 2016-11-14
                [views] => 1760
                [participations] => 41
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 2017-01-01
                [views] => 122
                [participations] => 3
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 2016-10-06
                [views] => 2113
                [participations] => 102
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 2016-08-31
                [views] => 1986
                [participations] => 110
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 2016-07-26
                [views] => 127
                [participations] => 3
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 2016-12-03
                [views] => 826
                [participations] => 24
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 2016-11-13
                [views] => 796
                [participations] => 20
            )

    )

[by_category] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => announcements
                [views] => 2639
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => assignments
                [views] => 21611
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => collaborations
                [views] => 6
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => conferences
                [views] => 6
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => discussions
                [views] => 29962
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => files
                [views] => 13649
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => general
                [views] => 23497
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => grades
                [views] => 5473
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => groups
                [views] => 231
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => modules
                [views] => 27258
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => other
                [views] => 18186
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => pages
                [views] => 16576
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [category] => quizzes
                [views] => 6206
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

its easy by foreach:

```
foreach($array['by_category'] as $category){
    echo 'id='. $category['id'] . ' , name='.$category['category'];
}
```